# Invalid image is uploaded to Amazon s3 of size in bytes

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload image to my bucket, image is uploaded but it is uploaded in bytes(14 bytes).

When I downloaded the image using s3 browser it shows invalid image.

Below is my code snippet:

```
if ($s3->isBucketAvailable($bucketName)) {


 $request = $this->getRequest();
    $postFile = $request->getFiles ()->toArray ();
    foreach ( $postFile as $key => $value ) { 
        if ($value ['name'] !== "") {
            $randString = Rand::getString ( rand ( 18, 20 ), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', true );
            $microTime = microtime ( true ) * 10000;
            $ext = pathinfo($value ["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $id = 'postImg_' . $randString . $microTime . '.'.$ext;
            $filename = date("Ymd").'/'. $id;
            $filename = $bucketName.'/'.$filename; 
            if($s3->putObject($filename, $value['tmp_name'], $s3::S3_ACL_PRIVATE)) {
                echo "Image posted";
            } else { 
                echo "error";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In place of `$value['tmp_name']` I also tried image url but it is also showing the same issue.

Comment: I suspect those 14 bytes are the `/tmp/file_path` where the file was sitting on your server, and you've stored the filename instead of the file content in the body of the S3 object... obviously not your intention, but a pretty likely explanation.  Go to your bucket, in the console, find the file, change the `Content-Type` to `text/plain` and download it again, to confirm this.  If that doesn't help you figure it out, you may want to mention which php sdk version you are running so someone can explain whether you are perhaps using the wrong method or wrong args, or just what.